# Passing custom props to router component in react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using React Router to create a multi page app. My main component is `<App/>` and it renders all of the routing to to child components. I'm trying to pass props via the route, and based on some [research](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105) I did, the most common way for child components to tap into props passed down is via the `this.props.route` object that they inherit. However, this object is undefined for me. On my `render()` function in the child component, I `console.log(this.props)` and am return an object that looks like this

```
{match: Object, location: Object, history: Object, staticContext: undefined}
```

Doesn't look like the props I expected at all. Here is my code in detail.

Parent Component (I'm trying to pass the word "hi" down as a prop called "test" in all of my child components):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Link from 'react-router';
import React from 'react';

import Home from './Home.jsx';
import Nav from './Nav.jsx';
import Progress from './Progress.jsx';
import Test from './Test.jsx';



export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this._fetchPuzzle = this._fetchPuzzle.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact test="hi" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/progress" test="hi" component={Progress} />             
            <Route path="/test" test="hi" component={Test} />
            <Route render={() => <p>Page not found!</p>} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Child:

```
import React from 'react';
const CodeMirror = require('react-codemirror');
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

require('codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript')

require('codemirror/mode/xml/xml');
require('codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown');

export default class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(props)

  }

  render() {
    const options = {
      lineNumbers: true,  
      theme: 'abcdef'    
      // mode: this.state.mode
    };
    console.log(this.props)

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>First page bro</h1>        
        <CodeMirror value='code lol' onChange={()=>'do something'} options={options} />
      </div>);
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to React so my apologies if I'm missing something obvious.
Thanks!

Comment: What information do you want to extract from the `route` object? in react-router v4 you should be able to retrieve the same info from either `match` or `location`

Comment: @AnthonyKong I'm trying to extract the "test" property.`<Route path="/" exact test="hi" component={Home} />`. I was under the impression that the rendered `<Home/>` component would have access to an object that held this value. I looked into the `match` and `location` objects and didn't find my prop.

Comment: how about `match.params.test`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong Doesn't seem to be there. Only has `__proto__`

Comment: Don't know why that value is not present, but alternative of that is, pass that value like this: `<Route path="/test" render={(props) => <Test {...props} test="hi"/>} />` and access that by `this.props.test`.

Comment: @MayankShukla Thank you. This delivered. Odd that the value wasn't present using the other technique.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can pass props to the component by making use of the `render` prop to the `Route` and thus inlining your component definition. According to **[the DOCS:](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)**

> This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the
>   undesired remounting explained above.Instead of having a new React
>   element created for you using the `component` prop, you can pass in a
>   function to be called when the `location` matches. The render prop
>   receives all the same route props as the component render prop

So you can pass the prop to component like

```
 <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => (<Home test="hi" {...props}/>)} />
```

and then you can access it like

```
this.props.test
```

in your `Home` component

> **P.S.** Also make sure that you are passing `{...props}` so that the
>   default router props like `location, history, match etc` are also getting passed on to the `Home` component
>   otherwise the only prop that is getting passed down to it is `test`.

Comment: This worked thank you. Odd that the method I tried in my question above didn't work.

Comment: Yeah I had done that analysis in my local setup before answering this, took me some time in that

Comment: is this the recommended approach? It looks like a quick fix?

Comment: you should add the props parameter to the function you pass in and use it in the component 'Home' with {...props} otherwise you would lose the standard props react router v4 passes in

Comment: @speedDeveloper, I don't think its a quick fix, and the router props will be passed if you pass it to the component in `render()`. I missed that part in the answer. However I updated it to include the same