# React Router re-render when using arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have App.js with route

```
<Route path="/home" component={() => <Home changeAuth={this.changeAuth} auth={auth} />}/>
```

But when i use component  to display modal with:

```
<Link to="/home/info"> <span class="logout">App Info</span></Link>
<Route path="/home/info" component={Info} />
```

Component  was re-render and run componentDidMount.
It's not when i use `<Route component ={Home}/>` but i want using props.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle, unable get your problem?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [passing-custom-props-to-router-component-in-react-router-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255415/passing-custom-props-to-router-component-in-react-router-v4/44255850#44255850)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Route render prop, not component in this case:

```
<Route path="/home" render={() => <Home changeAuth={this.changeAuth} auth={auth} />}/>
```

PS: this depends on the version of react-router that you are using, so I'm assuming you are using v4

From the [Route Component Documentation:](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#component)

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
>   router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
>   given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
>   component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
>   results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
>   mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
>   an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
>   children prop (below).