# Pass props through route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In react how can I configure a route to pass props. for example my route.tsx is:

```
export const routes = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
    <Route path='/counter' component={ Counter } />
    <Route path='/fetchdata' component={ FetchData } />
  </Layout>
);
```

How can I pass some data as props to my `Counter` component when ever /counter is evoked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing custom props to router component in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255415/passing-custom-props-to-router-component-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) prop.

```
  <Route 
     path='/counter' 
     render={(props) => (
       <Counter {...props} count={5} />
     )} 
  />
```

Answer (score 8):

This will do the work: [Render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)

```
    <Route
      path='/dashboard'
      render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
    />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if OP doesnt need the router props he doesnt need to pass {...props}

Comment: Correct, that's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in other answers, this is handled by the [render prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func), which gives the example:

```html
<Route path="/home" render={() => <div>Home</div>}/>
```

However, I (and many others) find this syntax pretty ugly. In the [original issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105) on prop passing with Route, there's a [well-liked](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105#issuecomment-289195202) wrapper which I wanted to surface, I've made some improvements and propose this terse and effective wrapper:

```js
const PropsRoute = ({component, path, ...otherProps}) => (
  <Route {...otherProps} path={path} render={routeProps => 
      React.createElement(component, {...otherProps, ...routeProps})
    } />
)
```

This can be used as might be expected:

```html
<Router>
   <main>
     <PropsRoute exact path="/" component={Home} auth={this.state.auth} />
   </main>
</router>
```

Note that doing this will pass the Route props down to the component. *Any* prop passed to Route that isn't 'component' or 'path' will be passed down to the component. In this formulation, any routeProps (passed by the react-router) will override custom props passed via this syntax.

This can then be quite easily expanded on to make the common login pattern:

```js
const AuthedRoute = ({auth, ...props}) =>
  !auth.valid()? <Redirect to="/login" />: <PropsRoute {...{...props, auth: auth}} />;
```

Edit: I've largely abandoned this approach as of 2019, in favour of something like this:

```js
<Route {...{
    path: "/path/to/component",
    render: ({ location }) => <MyComponent {...{
        location
    }}/>
}}/>
```

This can appear a bit more gnarly, but it makes deeply nested render trees much clearer, and lets you use full Javascript in your JSX parameters.

Comment: There is problem. Refresh page on every click.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things you could create a wrapper around `<Route>`:

```
const RouteWrapper = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    const childrenWithProps = props => React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { ...props }))}
    return <Route {...props} render={childrenWithProps} />
}
```

Usage:

```
<RouteWrapper
    exact
    path="/">
    <Component myProp={38} />
</RouteWrapper>
```