# What does that props mean?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

In this example:

```
class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route
          path="/todos/new"
          component={props => <NewTodoForm {...props} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the NewTodoForm component, it reaches the `{...props}` by using

```
this.props.history.push("url")
```

I am confused that in `{...props}`, why does it use `props` rather than `this.props`? I know that is a stateless function and props is a parameter. But where does that props come from?

Any help or comment will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: props are passed in component markup. For example: If you have dom component```<TodoList prop1="val1" prop2="val2">``` then your component's props will be ```{prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2"}```

Comment: Check this post. It will help you understand more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255415/passing-custom-props-to-router-component-in-react-router-v4/44255850#44255850

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
component={props => <NewTodoForm {...props} />}
```

is using the [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern, i.e. having a prop that is a function that returns something for the parent component to render.

The parameters passed to a render prop function could be anything, but in react-router's [`component` prop's case](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/component), it'll be the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-props) object, i.e. `{match, location, history}`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it really helps.